# how run jupyternotebook on ssh server?

Tags: linux, ssh, jupyter-notebook

I have a large file which I store it in my ssh server but want to use jupyternotebook to do some down stream analysis.
I tried this method in the terminal:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=<port number>
ssh -N -L <port number>:localhost:<port number> <REMOTE_USER>@<REMOTE_HOST>
```

which then I copied the and pasted `http://localhost:9999` onto a browser typed in my password. It opened up the jupyter notebook but when I tried to access the data
doing

```
!cd /path/to/directory/file
```

in the jupyter notebook but says `zsh:cd:1: no such file or directory: /var2/sj-won/pbmc_normal_L001/outs/filtered_feature_bc_matrix`

not sure where if I made a mistake when setting jupyter notebook in the terminal or the !cd command in the notebook.

Comment: I suspect you wanted the magic command `%cd ... ` and not `!cd ... `. In case you aren't aware, the exclamation point just makes a temporary shell and runs commands on the rest of that line and then discards that temporary shell at the end of the line. So while you may successfully change directories in the temporary shell (when the path is correct), it won't change anything beyond that line. See the highlighted 'Note' at the bottom of [the documentation about %cd](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-cd).

Comment: The path still needs to be correct though for when using `%cd`. Have you explored where the actual notebook considers its initial working directory? Run `pwd` in the notebook and see what it says. (Note that doesn't need a symbol because of automagics being on by default in most modern jupyter and so it uses [%pwd](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pwd) behind the scenes. The automagics trick will work for `cd` too. Essentially use `%` symbol with standard shell commands to be explicit.)

Comment: When `pwd` on the notebook it comes out as `/Users/home` But the file is in a different directory and when I tried `%cd /var2/....` where my data is stored it comes out as `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: /var2/.....` @Wayne

Comment: You have a directory at the highlest level on your drive that is called `var2`? Sounds off. Is `var2` inside `home`? Syntax is extremely important here.  And you aren't providing enough information for anyone to understand what is happening on your system. (For example, add text results of running `pwd `inside your notebook and show full path to your notebook file from a terminal, etc.) Why don't you simply use the absolute full path to your notebook and to where your Jupyter starts out until you sort things out. Is there a possibility of a permissions problem? This your own personal computer?

Comment: yes it's my own computer and the server is work's since i deal with large biological data (50GB+ per file). I have the full access to the server afik when the co-worker set it up for me. Everyone has to manage their own data so should be able to have full access would be odd not to.

In the terminal, after I enter my ssh login, `cd /var2/<my id>` is where I store all the data since it has the largest storage capacity. since the file is too large to do it on local (only 16GB ram) Im trying to run my module using jupyter notebook with out trying to transfer file from ssh to local vice versa.

Comment: If you use the Jupyter terminal, not the notebook, can you navigate from where you said you start `/Users/home` to the `/var2/` directory? Or another way to approach questioning what is going on ... Does the remote server have `zsh` as the main shell? That `zsh:cd:1: no such file or directory:` part of the error in your OP makes me think you aren't running things where you think you are? It seems you are accessing the shell of your local Mac maybe? (Just a guess based on seeing zsh.) You really need to be looking a the the devices things are running on in addition to the absolute path.

Comment: @Wayne I think I was accessing via local Mac. Should I be mounting to access the files and directories in the ssh?

Comment: Okay, now we are getting somewhere. I'm more familiar with using an SSH tunnel, like you show in your first lines of code, to port Jupyter running on the remote machine to allow the running notebooks or JupyterLab to show up in the browser of my local machine. Because in that case Jupyter is running on the remote machine, it of course sees the remote machines files. In your case, it looks like you are trying to do something like [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/168145/how-to-use-ssh-tunneling/), I think(?). (The order of your items looks opposite though and so that is why I say, 'I think'.)...

Comment: The key thing in there is the line " if the database server offered web access, ...". Does your remote server offer web access that will allow local Jupyter to browse it's file system? It doesn't seem like it does? Backing up to the start of all this ... What guide are you following to work this out? It might help debug if I had examples. Like I said, I'm really used to running Jupyter on the remote machine and using a tunnel to forward use of it to my local browser and not the direction you describe.

Comment: Or looking at this another way... I think you need to clarify your goal at this point. Your title of this post reads opposite of what you actually seem to be doing. At best, it is vague. Your title implies you want to run Jupyter on a remote server, but you seem to be running Jupyter locally since you now say, "@Wayne I think I was accessing via local Mac." In other words, what computational resources should Jupyter be using? If you indeed want to use Jupyter locally, you just need to be doing whatever you normally do to make it so you can say edit server files with Microsoft Word.

Comment: "I think I was accessing via local Mac" was meant that I was running jupyter on local when it gave me `zsh:cd:1:` message. The jupyter should be using the resource in the ssh server and yes it has it has web access. 
The guide I'm following to work this out: https://coderwall.com/p/tixbrq/mount-remote-dir-in-the-osx-finder-using-sshfs-and-homebrew